# Cant view my Applications directory contents because of Chrome

Tags: linux, macos, google-chrome, bash

I'm try to reach the contents of a specific application via terminal but every time I cd into the Applications directory and the ls I get the following

```
Admin-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ cd Applications
Admin-MacBook-Pro:Applications admin$ ls
Chrome Apps.localized
```

I thought all my Applications had simply moved into that sub-directory but when I cd into it I get the following

```
Admin-MacBook-Pro:Applications admin$ cd "Chrome Apps.localized"
Admin-MacBook-Pro:Chrome Apps.localized admin$ ls

Default apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf.app    Defaul coobgpohoikkiipiblmjeljniedjpjpf.app Icon?
Default blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo.app    Default pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia.app
```

Does someone know what's happening? and as to how can I solve this so I can properly cd into my Applications directory and see its contents ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this line in your question:

> Admin-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ cd Applications

You are operating in your own user directory, which is `/Users/$USER/`, indicated by the `~`. Typing that command will put you in `/Users/$USER/Applications/`, which can hold user-specific applications and is indeed where Chrome puts its 'Applications'.

All applications are typically (there are exceptions) stored in `/Applications/`, located in the root directory of your hard drive. The proper command to go there is:

> Admin-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ cd /Applications

Note the prefix `/` to go to the absolute path. Without it, `cd` will try to go to the folder with that name in the current directory (you can check that with `pwd`).